# Tag Synonyms listing page does not show the full page header

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, tag-synonyms

This affects all Trilogy sites.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

Look at the top -- all that's shown is the "about" and "faq" links, and the search box. This should show the envelope, your user name, badges, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed fixed and fixed ... was missing a call to initialize the user.