# Privileges landing page shows a different version of the top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, privileges

The landing page you get when visiting your own, or another user's, has a different top bar that seems outdated. This is slightly unusual as the top bar is otherwise matched in all of the specific privilege pages. Things like your log in and stats are gone, and the presence of "about" on Meta are changed. Below are some screenshots on a site that I'm logged in on, versus a site that I'm anonymously checking.

[image]

Or if you want hands-on, check out mine here and see how the top bar changes: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/user/146126

Comment: This also happens on error pages.

Comment: I [reported the same thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57138/tag-synonyms-listing-page-does-not-show-the-full-page-header) when the tag synonyms page was first released. Should be a quick fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to manually initialize the user if we don't explicitly reference it in the page, because it is lazy loaded.

Comment: The user info isn't shown on the main privileges page.