# Header doesn't display correct links on "Page Not Found" page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface

I just tried to visit the profile of an MSO user, but it turns out that that user recently deleted his account, so I got the "Page Not Found" page. It looked like this:

[image: screenshot of Page Not Found page header with missing links]

The "log out" and "tools" links were missing from the top bar. I know the site knows who I am because I've been logged in all day with no issues and the badges/privileges banners are still there.

The same behavior occurs on questions that don't exist, except that I don't always see the badges/privileges banners on those.

Here are a sample [nonexistent user page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13240154/jonathan-sampson) and a sample [nonexistent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7025330/add-export-log-feature-to-chat).

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66887/privileges-landing-page-shows-a-different-version-of-the-top-bar) [reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57138/tag-synonyms-listing-page-does-not-show-the-full-page-header) for other pages that have the issue. The issue is a lack of initializing the user.

Comment: Thanks, @Grace. My search focused a bit too heavily on "Page Not Found."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, this is too expensive to do on all page not found pages. Sorry.